# ARM Keil Version 5 [Expected a ')']

Tags: c, syntax, keil, stm32f0

I am using the Keil version 5 toolchain to program STM32F0 Series and I am not able to resolve the below-given error.
I am sure I am missing something in it, but having a hard time finding it out.

```
> ..\Core\Src\max2871.c(169): error:  #18: expected a ")"
      if (((test_data[2] & ((1 << 28) | (1 << 27) | (1 << 26))) >> 26) == 0b110)
```

Thanks in Advance.

here is the complete function block:

```
void plo_check_lock_status(void)
{
    // Saves the status only if the muxout pin is set correctly.
    if (((test_data[2] & ((1 << 28) | (1 << 27) | (1 << 26))) >> 26) == 0b110)
        plo_buff_push(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(PLO_MUXOUT_GPIO_Port, PLO_MUXOUT_Pin));
    else
        HAL_NVIC_DisableIRQ(EXTI0_1_IRQn);
}
```

Comment: Check the line above this one.

Comment: `if ((test_data[2] >> 26) & 7)` As far as I remember Keil does not support gcc extension `0bxxxx`.

Comment: void plo_check_lock_status(void)
{
    // Saves the status only if the muxout pin is set correctly.
    if (((test_data[2] & ((1 << 28) | (1 << 27) | (1 << 26))) >> 26) == 0b110)
        plo_buff_push(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(PLO_MUXOUT_GPIO_Port, PLO_MUXOUT_Pin));
    else
        HAL_NVIC_DisableIRQ(EXTI0_1_IRQn);
}

Comment: is the binary literals syntax (`0bxxx`) supported on this compiler? Replace the `0b110` with `0x6` and see if the error goes away. This syntax is not standard.

Comment: You are correct, `0bxxx` BIN format was not supported by the compiler, So changed that to HEX format `0x6` and the issue is resolved. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: To find the exact location with a compiler that reports only the line number, you can temporarily split the line into multiple lines, placing each token (symbol, value, operator) on its own line.

Answer (score 0):

You use if statement but you forgot to used { and }. When you used if statement
you have two ways:

1. Use if statement by single state and ;
   If(...) ...;
2. Use if statement by multy states and use {}.
   If(...){
   ...
   }
   Else{
   ...
   }
   Good Luck